Iterate over list of strings to retrieve groups of strings
Given the following list:
inp = ["arg1:", "list", "of", "args", "arg2:", "other", "list"]

How can I develop a dictionary like this?
out = {"arg1": ["list", "of", "args"], "arg2": ["other", "list"]}

It's basically a case of:

Loop through the input list until we find an element suffixed with a colon (e.g. arg1:)
Use this (without the colon) to create a key in a dictionary with a value of an empty list
Continue looping through the input list, adding each element to this key's list value, until another element is found with a colon
Rinse and repeat until all elements are processed in this way

Other examples would be:
inp = ["test:", "one", "help:", "two", "three", "four"]
out = {"test": ["one"], "help": ["two", "three", "four"]
---
inp = ["one:", "list", "two:", "list", "list", "three:", "list", "list", "list"]
out = {"one": ["list"], "two": ["list", "list"], "three": ["list", "list", "list"]}

This feels like it should be relatively straightforward (albeit probably not a one-liner!) but I just can't get my head round it.
Any advice appreciated.

You basically explained the algorithm, now you just need to write it in Python.

yeah, I know what I want to achieve. I guess the bit I'm struggling with is "how do I keep looping over the loop until all of the elements are processed"

You don't need any recursion, just take the items one by one, if you have a colon change the key. Use dict.sedefault as helper to initialize the empty lists:
inp = ['arg1:', 'list', 'of', 'args', 'arg2:', 'other', 'list']

out = {}
key = None # default key

for item in inp:
    if item.endswith(':'):
        key = item.removesuffix(':')
        continue
    out.setdefault(key, []).append(item)

Output:
{'arg1': ['list', 'of', 'args'], 'arg2': ['other', 'list']}


have chosen this one as I find it the easiest to read/understand. thank you

I don't believe there's a "pythonic" way of doing this, without using some lambdas which would make the code some what unreadable.
But as you point out, it's pretty straight forward to implement this with a loop and "exploiting" the fact that dict's are mutable:
inp = ["arg1:", "list", "of", "args", "arg2:", "other", "list"]

result = {}
reference_point = result
for item in inp:
    if item.endswith(':'):
        if (item := item.rstrip(':')) not in result:
            result[item] = []

        reference_point = result[item]
    else:
        reference_point.append(item)

print(result)

There's some edge cases that I did not take into account, mainly because you did not specify what should happen in such cases. Like what if the input starts with a "value" and not a item that ends with :.
But this should give you a general idea of how you could solve it.

if the list starts with an item that doesn't contain a colon, I will raise an exception - so that's easy enough to deal with. I can therefore guarantee the list starts with such an item
thanks for this. I think I used the wrong word in the title, or over-thought how it needed to be written

One straight forward way is to just write the exact algorithm you described.
def foo(xs: list[str]) -> dict[str, list[str]]:
    d = {}
    for x in xs:
        if x[-1] == ':': d[x[:-1]] = l = []
        else: l.append(x)
    return d


inp = ["test:", "one", "help:", "two", "three", "four"]
out = {"test": ["one"], "help": ["two", "three", "four"]}

assert foo(inp) == out

inp = ["one:", "list", "two:", "list", "list", "three:", "list", "list", "list"]
out = {"one": ["list"], "two": ["list", "list"], "three": ["list", "list", "list"]}
assert foo(inp) == out


I personally don't prefer this, as it's very imperative, and not pythonic or functional in nature.
I'll update the answer, if I manage to write a short functional one.

You're right, it probably should not be a one-liner.
out = {s[:-1]: (v := []) for s in inp if s[-1:] == ':' or v.append(s)}

Attempt This Online!

Well but it still works...

import itertools


L = ["arg1:", "list", "of", "args", "arg2:", "other", "list"]
answer = {}
key = None
for k, group in itertools.groupby(L, lambda s: s.endswith(":")):
    if k:
        key = list(group)[0].rstrip(":")
    else:
        answer[key] = list(group)

Result:
In [313]: answer
Out[313]: {'arg1:': ['list', 'of', 'args'], 'arg2:': ['other', 'list']}


key = next(group)[:-1] (remove colon)

@MarkTolonen: You're absolutely right. Thanks for the bugreport

Here's a simple function that handles lists that are in order and start with a key. It works for your example cases and handles the argument of the function with a default empty list (an empty list will return an empty dict).
def convertListToDict(argList = []):
    returnDict = {}
    newKey = None

    for arg in argList:
        if arg[-1] == ":":
            newKey = arg[:-1]
            returnDict[newKey] = []
        elif newKey:
            returnDict[newKey].append(arg)

    return returnDict


While @mozway's solution works, it unnecessarily incurs the overhead of a dict lookup and the instantiation of a new list for every iteration where the item does not end with :.
You can instead keep a reference to the last-created list and simply append new items to the referenced list:
inp = ["arg1:", "list", "of", "args", "arg2:", "other", "list"]
out = {}
for i in inp:
    if i.endswith(':'):
        out[i.removesuffix(':')] = lst = []
    else:
        lst.append(i)

out becomes:
{'arg1': ['list', 'of', 'args'], 'arg2': ['other', 'list']}

Demo here
